# Freeing adjacency list

Tags: c, graph, free, adjacency-list

As an assignment I had to write a code that generates a random graph with a given probability, and check the diameter.
I've created a function that calls bfs V times (V being the number of vertices), letting each vertex be the starting vertex and storing the biggest path it finds.
After that I must run the code 500 times for 10 different probabilities (5000 times in total)
My code reaches a usage of 3GB and crashes, at some point it says a pointer is null, one life after allocating memory for it, I'm guessing this means the PC physically ran out of space to allocate.
I'll put the function I wrote to free the adjacency list after each iteration, is there something I'm doing wrong?

The graph is represented by an array of structs, this array represents the vertices of the graph.
If a vertex does have anything connected to it, that same index of the array will point to a linked list containing all of the neighbors.

I will include the functions in the following order:
Struct for array
struct for linked lists pointed to by array.
Array decleration in the main function.
function for edge creation
function for freeing graph.

```
//Struct for array:
typedef struct List
{
int vertex;
Node* head; 
}List;

//struct for linked lists pointed to by array:
typedef struct Node
{
int e;
struct Node* next; 
}Node;

//declaration for array of vertices:
List** vertices = (List*)calloc(v, sizeof(List));

//function that builds random graph, and uses "add edge" to create one if 
needed
int build_random_graph(int v, float p, List** vertices) 
{                                                      
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < v; i++)
{
    vertices[i] = malloc(sizeof(List)); //Creating array of vertices.
    vertices[i]->head = NULL;
    vertices[i]->vertex = i;
}
srand(time(0)); 
for (i = 0; i < v; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < v; j++)
    {
        if ((j > i) && (rand() / (double)RAND_MAX <= p)) 
        {                                                
            add_edge(i, j, vertices);                    
        }
    }
}
}


//Function for edge creation:
int add_edge(int i, int j, List** vertices) 
{
Node* dest;
Node* src;
Node* temp;
if (vertices[i]->head == NULL)
{
    src = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    src->e = j;
    src->next = NULL;
    vertices[i]->head = src;
}
else
{
    dest = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    dest->e = j; //Each time. this is where the error occurs.
    dest->next = NULL;
    temp = vertices[i]->head;
    while (temp->next)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = dest;
    
}

if (vertices[j]->head == NULL)
{
    src = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    src->e = i;
    src->next = NULL;
    vertices[j]->head = src;
}
else
{
    dest = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    dest->e = i;
    dest->next = NULL;
    temp = vertices[j]->head;
    while (temp->next)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = dest;
    
}

//Freeing the graph:
void freelist(int v, List** vertices)
{

int i;
for (i = 0; i < v; i++)
{
    Node* t = vertices[i]->head;
    Node* p;
    while (t->next != NULL)
    {
        p = t;
        t = t->next;
        free(p);
    }
    free(t);
}
for (i = 0; i < v; i++)
{
    List* ptr;
    ptr = vertices[i];
    free(ptr);
}
free(vertices);
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the definitions of any of your types _or_ how you allocated the thing you're freeing. I don't know how anyone can help without those. You edit them into your question, or try using valgrind or your compiler's address sanitizer to diagnose the problems locally, or even do both in parallel.

Comment: Oh, and does _at some point it says a pointer is null_ occur when you check the return from `malloc` or something similar? If not, you could just have an initialization bug or something. If it does, that's relevant information that should also be edited into the question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've edited the question, if any more information is needed I will gladly edit again :)